# How to take input Array in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to take input like this. Here 2 is number of test cases 4 is number of input in Array respectively.
Here is sample of input.

2

4

1 5 3 2

3

3 2 7

Comment: Is this for a competitive programming site with an online judge, like HackerRank? Usually on those sites you are given the code that reads and parses the input, and you don't need to write it yourself.

Comment: Even if it isn't, *some* attempt of your own to write it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
test_cases = []
number_of_cases = input ('Enter the number of test cases : ')
for index in range (int (number_of_cases)) :
    test_cases.append ([]) 
    prompt = 'Enter the number of digits for test ' + str (index + 1) + ' : '
    number_of_digits = input (prompt)
    for count in range (int (number_of_digits)) :
        prompt = 'Enter test case number ' + str (count + 1) + ' : '
        test_cases[index].append (input (prompt))
print (test_cases)
```

Comment: it is correct but I want to take array input in one line separate by space.